# Change cells that contain a strike through to a negative number

Tags: vba, excel

It's been so long since I've used VBA (and I was never very good with it to begin with), that trying to figure this out on my own would take longer than is prudent.
I have a couple of workbooks with about 11 or 12 worksheets each.  There are cells on the worksheets that contain numbers and have been formatted with a strike-through.  I need a script to go through each sheet and change each cell that contains a number that has been stuck-through(?) to a negative number.  Would someone be willing to help out on this?

Thanks

Comment: Because Stack Overflow is not a free code writing service you will need at least start on your own and show what you have already tried. Show us where you got stuck and ask a specific question to your code. Reading [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/284237/3219613) might help you too.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't like VBA then you can create a simple VBA function to help you.

Hold down Alt and F11 then copy and paste this into the VBA script, save and close.

```
Function HasStrike(Rng As Range) As Boolean
Application.Volatile
HasStrike = Rng.Font.Strikethrough
End Function
```

You can now use HasStrike() as a True/False function and do anything you want with the value of the cell (eg. use an if statement).

If you really want a VBA script then this can provide you with a starting point.